# Is diffraction empirically derived or based off something else?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, diffraction

after reading about diffraction I am confused on how its effect came to be understood.

Can one derive diffraction from the wave equation and base principles or is it a result of empirical observations?

Comment: The Kirchhoff integral theorem shows that diffraction patterns can be derived mathematically from the wave equation alone.

Answer (score 2):

Diffraction can be derived from the wave equation and basic principles, but the empirical observations came first, historically. So, as stated, the answer is: "both"

Historically, diffraction was observed before it was explained with the wave equation. Young's double slit experiment started the idea of light as a wave more than 50 years before Maxwell's equations (the "base principles" behind diffraction).

The wave equation also predicts diffraction. The math can be somewhat involved, but it can be summarized as follows: In 3 dimensions, only a plane wave can travel in just one direction - if the wave has any limits (i.e. if it has any cross-sectional shape), those limits (its shape), it must change as it travels. If you fix the wave shape at one point in the direction of travel (say, by using the shape of Young's double slit), then you can very accurately calculate a diffraction pattern somewhere further along the direction of travel.

There are many good resources which explain diffraction, including https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction and any good optics textbook (unless it only has geometric optics).

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, I read the article on the Huygens–Fresnel principle but this principle wasn't proven from the wave equation, it was taken as a physical fact.

Comment: On some level, Huygens-Fresnel and Maxwell's equations are equivalent. For purposes of this question, the Huygens-Fresnel principle is another "base principle" which predicts the phenomena. Huygens and Fresnel also worked after Young's double slit, and their principle can also predict diffraction effects.

Comment: Hmm, for clarification sake do you have a reference that derives diffraction explicitly from the wave equation?